# O que significa fetch em relação ao Git?

Tags: git, push-notification, fetch

- Qual a função dele?
- É um comando do Git ou apenas uma explicação relacionada a um comando?

Comment: Aparentemente sim, então ele é de fato um comando, além de ser usado em outras situações.

Comment: Quando tiver duvida sobre um comando sempre leia a documentação: https://git-scm.com/docs/ (pt-BR: https://git-scm.com/docs/git/pt_BR)